# TinyMCE: hidden textarea

Tags: html, css, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I try to setup tinyMCE on my web site.
This is my settings:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extensions/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "exact",
        elements: "mceContent",
        language : "ru",
        theme : "advanced",
        forced_root_block : false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,

        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,formatselect,forecolor,backcolor,link,unlink,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,bullist,numlist,|,pasteword,pastetext,table,image,|,undo,redo,|,code,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        height: 400,
        width: 680,

        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "blue",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        relative_urls : false
    });
</script>
```

This is my html code:

```
<textarea class="span8" name="mceContent" id="mceContent" rows="15" 
    style="width: 40em; height: 20em" >
        {$mceContent}
</textarea>
```

When I open this page text area is hidden. This is html code I see in browser:

```
<textarea class="span8" name="mceContent" id="mceContent" rows="15" 
style="width: 40em; height: 20em; visibility: hidden;">                 
</textarea>
```

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: TinyMCE does that so that it can replace the textarea with the editor. Does the editor not show up?

Comment: @TiesonT., now, it doesn't show up

Comment: Does Firebug (or the developer tools of your browser, if you don't have Firebug) report any errors?

Comment: @TiesonT., yes, there was an error with loading language js file. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

You are running `tinymce.init()` before the DOM is properly loaded. You need to wrap your `init()` inside a `document.ready`:

```
document.addEventListener('DomContentLoaded', function(){

    tinyMCE.init({
        // your init options
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is not an issue. bcoz u have passed ***elements: "mceContent"*** value to tinymce constructor,by doing this the plugin will hide the matched element and it will the the editor instead.